# Outputting answers of predict() to a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, svm, predict

I am looking to output the answers of predict to a data frame so I can identify the top matches.

The data is FAQ doc with two columns -  multiple questions to one answer.

If I use

Predict(svmfit, data)

Then it outputs multiple possible matches, but when I use

As.data.frame(predict(svmfit, data)) it outputs only the top answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the input in reproducible form? See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.